# How to use scss modules in Next.js server components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, next.js, sass-modules

I am trying to implement server components in my Next.js app. I'm using scss modules for styling.

A typical component in my project looks like this:

```
//MyComponent.client.jsx

import s from './MyComponent.module.scss';

export const MyComponent = ({ props }) => {
return <div id={ s.wrapper }>{ props.stuff }</div>
};
```

When I change this to: `MyComponent.server.jsx`

Styling ceases to work, and I don't get any errors.

How can I maintain this functionality in a server component?

Comment: shouldn't it be `<div className={s.wrapper} >` instead of  `id` ?

Comment: You may use either. (both don't work)